# Can we configure spring in play version 2.7.x ? If so then please share all the dependencies

Tags: spring, playframework

I am facing trouble configuring **spring** in my **play framework** to be able to use dependency injections of **spring** like **Autowired** and others.

I am using play version 2.7.x

I have tried using jroper github and cannot find **spring** module class in my code after adding **spring** guice

Comment: I've attempted to make this a little easier to read by removing a few words, fixing some caps & spelling, and separating sentences.  It might also help to provide a link in your text when referring to another site (github).

Answer (score 0):

The library you mention (https://github.com/jroper/play-spring) was a proof of concept for an older version of Play. To my knowledge there is no working integration for 2.7.x.

Generally, you should just use Guice for run-time dependency injection in Play (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).